# Read large data from Snowflake and write into a csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to read a huge table (10M rows) in `Snowflake` using `python` connector and write it into a csv file.

I read about `fetchmany` in snowfalke documentation,

```
fetchmany([size=cursor.arraysize])
Purpose
Fetches the next rows of a query result set and returns a list of sequences/dict. An empty sequence is returned when no more rows are available.
```

How do I use this and write to csv file in chunks until all the records are completely written?

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to write to data into stage unless you don't really have to use python for this.

The steps would be

1.

```
COPY INTO @~/stage_data
FROM (
(SELECT column_a, column_b, column_c 
FROM table_one
WHERE column_b IN (SELECT column_ FROM table_two )
)
file_format = (TYPE=CSV compression='gzip') single=true max_file_size=4900000000;
```

2.

```
get @~/data file:///~/;
```

Note : The example above uses `user stage` but you can change it to type of stage you like.

Comment: Thanks but I can't use the stage option. It has to be python and write the csv file in a server.

Answer (score 2):

Use **fetch_pandas_all()** and load the data to a dataframe with

`

```
import pandas as pd
import snowflake.connector
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
<connection details> )
cs = ctx.cursor()
query='select * from foo'
cs.execute(query)
df = cs.fetch_pandas_all()
df.to_csv('output.csv.gz',
  sep='|',
  header=True,
  index=False,
  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
  compression='gzip',
  quotechar='"',
  doublequote=True,
  line_terminator='\n')
```

`

Comment: or just use df.to_csv('output.csv) if you are sure the data is good to export

Comment: I tried this and received Quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, NameError: name 'CSV' is not definded

Comment: import csv <= resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

`fetchmany()` method will fetch the number of mentioned rows from your cursor result set. You can split your select statement eventually get number of records and execute parallel using python cursor.

for example if my table has 2000 records:

```
select * from table where id between 1 and 1000;
select * from table where id between 1001 and 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note i have given my connection details in another file that i am importing. I am selecting 2 columns from database testdb and table store_sales

```
import snowflake.connector
from connections import conn
from snowflake.connector import DictCursor
import csv

cur = conn.cursor(DictCursor)
try:
    sql = "use testdb"
    cur.execute(sql)
    sql = "select Branch_id , city from store_sales"
    cur.execute(sql)
    with open('file.csv', 'w+', newline="") as f:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(f , delimiter=',')
        for rec in cur:
            csv_writer.writerow([rec['BRANCH_ID'],rec['CITY']])       
finally:
    cur.close()
```